# Working with multiple filesystem types: Python won't escape properly?

Tags: python, linux, fat32

In short, I'm trying to use `distutils.dir_util.copy_tree()` to copy data from an ext3 fs to a USB thumbdrive formatted using FAT32. The filenames tend to be long and contain interesting characters - which python strips/escapes fine for ext3. However, upon using `copy_tree()`, the list of illegal characters suddenly grows as it gets thrown onto the FAT32 thumbdrive, which python doesn't escape and results in this:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: u'/media/usb0/data/someweirdfile.with.dots.etc?satellite=1'
```

Obviously mode `wb` is fine, resulting in `?` being the illegal character. Short of re-writing `copy_tree()` (or escaping the filename), is there any way to easily tell python that it's working on a different filesystem type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Python does not know about the underlying filesystem (nor it should). It also doesn't escape anything in the filename — it's your job — `?` just happens to be a valid character for ext filesystems.

Answer (score 2):

Python (or any other use-space application) cannot possibly determine the filesystem type in the first place. That might work (albeit be very slow) for simple setups, but inevitably fails in the presence of changing hard and soft links and various filesystems - what do you do when FAT is mounted over FUSE or UnionFS?

Therefore, if you have a filesystem that can't have filenames containing a specific character, you'll have to remove that character manually.